# LINQ to Object to DataSet

Tags: linq-to-objects, linq-to-dataset

Can I do a LINQ Join from an List to a DataSet?  Are there any caveats to doing this?

Comment: Never tried it, but I suspect you would have to convert the `DataSet` to some sort of `IEnumerable` first, so that the join is apples-to-apples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are obvious performance problems ahead, depending on the size of each side of the join, so the real caveat is scale.

You won't have to do any converting, you can select rows out of the dataset/table as you would normally with LINQ and just include an "on" clause to tell it how to compare a row to your `List<T>`.